# Search for a criteria and get a sub-text

Tags: excel, search, substring

I have this text inside a cell from Excel:

```
1.Technical occurrence - Reason 1; (100%);04.02.2019
2.Systemic occurrence - Reason 2; (100%);06.02.2019
3.Technical escape - Reason 3; (100%);06.02.2019
4.Systemic escape - Reason 4; (100%);06.02.2019
```

I would like help me with a formula that is searching for `Systemic occurrence` criteria and get the corresponding text from that line (in this case `Reason 2`)

The structure of an item is always the same (`2.Systemic occurrence - Reason 2; (100%);06.02.2019`), but the order of items can differ.

Is it possible to do this with Excel with a formula?

Comment: Probably need more detail, but probably possible using FIND/SEARCH and MID formulae.

Comment: the whole line `1.Technical occurrence - Reason 1; (100%);04.02.2019` appears in one cell?

Comment: So, what do you want as the output? If you use find() to find "reason 1" then output the percentage or just "reason 1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`=IFERROR(IF(FIND("Systemic occurrence",A1),MID(A1,(FIND("-",A1,1)+2),((FIND(";",A1,1))-(FIND("-",A1,1)+2))),""),"")`

Results:

[image]

Comment: The text is inside of a single cell. Anyhow, thanks to your answer the final formula is: `=LEFT(RIGHT(B15,LEN(B15)-FIND("Systemic occurrence",B15,1)+1-LEN("Systemic occurrence")-3),FIND(";",RIGHT(B15,LEN(B15)-FIND("Systemic occurrence",B15,1)+1-LEN("Systemic occurrence")-3),1)-1)`